# Could you prove van der Waerden's theorem with a probabilistic argument

Tags: probability, combinatorics, alternative-proof, arithmetic-progressions

If we would try to prove the simplest case, that is: if we color the integers with 2 colors, then the coloring must contain an arithmetic progression of length 3.

Let $R_n$ be a randomly generated coloring of $n$ elements.
Define $f(n) = \mathbb{P}( R_n \text{ is AP-3 free})$, the chance that a randomly colored sequence of length $n$ does not have any arithmnetic progressions of length 3.

We can argue that  $f(2n)$ equals the chance that we don't have AP-3 over the $n$ even elements, multiplied by the chance that the odds are AP-3 free as well, multiplied by the chance that there aren't AP-3 on a combination of even and odd elements, given that the odd elements  are AP-3 free and the even elements are AP-3 free.

Now if we could find a sufficiently tight bound for the last probability, for example $\mathbb{P}(\text{ AP-3 free | odds and evens AP-3 free}) < f(n)^{1/2}$
Then we would have:
$$f(2n) < f(n)^2 f(n)^{1/2} = f(n)^{5/2}$$
$$f(n) < C^{n^{1.21}}$$
But then, for sufficiently large $n$ :  $f(n) < \frac{1}{2}^n$
But this would be problematic since there are only $2^n$ possible sequences. Therefore, we could conclude that there are $0$ feasible sequences of length $n$

Does this make any sense at all?

Comment: Yes, this is common approach in many combinatorical problems. But I am not sure if it's simple to find a good bound for probability of no AP-3 with both odds and evens.

Comment: I have seen something similar but then always to prove exisitence. What bound would I need? any exponantial bound would be enough right?

Comment: I am not sure any exponential bound will be enough - from $f(n) < 2^{n \alpha}$ you get $f(2n) < 2^{5/2 n \alpha}$, while you want to decrease exponent. But didn't check carefully.